# Ubuntu 18.04 no longer adds second joystick device for Sony DualShock3's gyro/accelerometer, new sony_hid driver

Tags: 18.04, sony

When the new hid_sony driver was released it split the gyro/accelerometer inputs into separate joystick devices.  Now a few weeks and update-upgrades later I find only the sticks, triggers, and buttons input device registers; that is not a problem for me. 
The loss of the gyro/accelerometer axises is a problem.  You can see the pastebin below when I connect the Sony PLAYSTATION(R)3 Controller Motion Sensors do not register as a joystick device while the Sony PLAYSTATION(R)3 Controller does get assigned a joystick.
Possibly just a config file needs to be edited to let the gyro device register(or for that matter choose to register the button analog inputs).  I have not changed my config since the new sony_hid was released and I at first had the two joysticks(physical and gyro) per Dualshock controller, but I am no longer getting that second gyro joystick device per Dualshock3 that I connect on either USB or bluetooth.
Is there some .config edit that can get the gyro axises to register as well as the (formerly available under the old driver) button analog axises for those who need that as well?

4.15.0-38-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:59:38 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
https://pastebin.com/zw8W8Ucs

Answer (score 2):

### Missing joystick device

I found your [bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1800839), but as it turned out it's a 'regression' in the `joydev` driver introduced in

[Input: joydev - blacklist ds3/ds4/udraw motion sensors](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/20ac95d52a28f55472a54cc751eeec49fd445cb1#diff-34c8d0c14a101d038ef2d2e7a1957559)

The author didn't explain the commit and I honestly can't see the reason behind it. I suggest you file a bug against it.

### The evdev device doesn't work either

There's also a minor bug with the evdev device node created by `hid_sony`: it is not user accessible, so the Motion Sensors won't show up in applications that use `evdev` devices instead of `joydev`. If that is your problem, create the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-ds3-accels-uaccess.rules` with the following content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event*", ATTRS{name}=="*Motion Sensors", TAG+="uaccess"
```

That rule will match every  device that ends in "Motion Sensors", so it also matches knockoff PS3-controllers like Gasia/Shanwan (the suffix is added by the `hid_sony` driver).

### I need the js* device and can't wait for the bug fix!

Since the `evdev` device is present, we can work around the `joydev` blacklist by creating a new `uinput` device that will not be blacklisted and forward the events to it.

Install `python-evdev` and create the following 3 files:

**~/.local/bin/evdev-forwarder.py**:

```
import evdev, sys

device = evdev.InputDevice(sys.argv[1])
joystick = evdev.UInput.from_device(device, name=(device.name + ' forwarded'))

for event in device.read_loop():
    joystick.write_event(event)
```

**~/.config/systemd/user/evdev-forwarder@.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Forwarding evdev device: %I

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="ARGS=%I"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python %h/.local/bin/evdev-forwarder.py $ARGS
```

**/etc/udev/rules.d/51-ds3-accels-workaround.rules**

```
KERNEL=="uinput", SUBSYSTEM=="misc", TAG+="uaccess"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event*", ATTRS{name}=="*Motion Sensors", TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}="evdev-forwarder@$env{DEVNAME}.service"
```

Note: the aforementioned `51-ds3-accels-uaccess.rules` is not necessary in this case.

### Analog buttons

Using the `hid_sony` driver, we'll probably never get the analog buttons back. There are several comments in the [source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/hid-sony.c) that indicate this, e.g.:

> We use the same axis and button mapping as the **DS3, which uses the Linux gamepad spec.**

...and ...

> The DS3 provides analog values for most buttons and even
>   for HAT axes through GD Pointer. L2 and R2 are reported among these
>   as well instead of as GD Z / RZ. Remap L2 and R2 and ignore other
>   analog 'button axes' as **there is no good way for reporting them**.

I highlighted those parts because they are probably the reason why. The [Linux Gamepad Specification](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/gamepad.html) doesn't mention analog buttons except left/right triggers.

Unless you modify the driver yourself or use something *really* outdated like [QtSixA/sixad](https://github.com/falkTX/qtsixa), you won't be able to use the face buttons' analog events.

Comment: danzel, I tried your fix, I wasn't sure if I needed to add an additional udev rule you describe in addition to your 51-ds3-accels-workaround.conf.  I tried pasting into SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event*", ATTRS{name}=="*Motion Sensors", TAG+="uaccess" into the new file /etc/udev/rules.d/sony_hid_fix.rules 

Very much not initiated into the world of HID devices and systems so there is probably more to do to get a gyro device I can use.
In any case the fix is not working whenever I have attempted it but I appreciate the help and posted the kernel rules change you found to the Launchpad bug.

Comment: @dave if you only need the `evdev` device, paste the first udev rule I mentioned into a file called e.g. `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-ds3-accels-uaccess.conf`. The file name doesn't really matter, only the number at the beginning is important to make sure it is evaluated at the correct time. After unplugging and replugging the controller, the evdev device node should be accessible, which you can try using `evtest` in a console. BTW, you can always run `sudo evtest` to make sure the device is created in the first place. If you do the python workaround, you don't need the first udev rule.

Comment: @dave I just edited the stupid mistake I made: of course the file extension has to be `.rules`, not `.conf`. Don't know how that happened...

Comment: I created and pasted in your contents for/etc/udev/rules.d/51-ds3-accels-uaccess.rules, ~/.local/bin/evdev-forwarder.py, ~/.config/systemd/user/evdev-forwarder@.service, /etc/udev/rules.d/51-ds3-accels-workaround.rulescode; reboot and pair... no new second joydev device for motion but I do see it under endev.
I go to bash and run python ~/.local/bin/evdev-forwarder.py  Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/david/.local/bin/evdev-forwarder.py", line 3, in <module> device = evdev.InputDevice(sys.argv[1])    IndexError: list index out of range...  I am not good enough to debug.

Comment: the `evdev-forwarder.py` takes the device node as argument, e.g. `/dev/input/eventX` (whatever number the motion sensor device gets assigned). Then, a new `/dev/input/jsX` device should be created, which you can test using e.g. `jstest-gtk`. I didn't know `evdev-joystick` before, but it seems that it only works for USB devices. BTW, it would probably help if you told us which application you want to use the joystick with.

Comment: So as sugessted by Roderick(awesome person) I can run evtest choose the Sony PLAYSTATION(R)3 Controller Motion Sensors and watch the changes in the motion sensor, but jstestgtk still shows just the sticks & buttons device

Comment: Ok, so you can already access the Motion Sensors device. When you run evtest, the line with the Motion Sensors device begins with `/dev/input/event23` in my case, the number will be different on your machine. When I run `python ~/.local/bin/evdev-forwarder.py /dev/input/event23`, two new devices are created: `/dev/input/event26` and `/dev/input/js3`. The first one you should see when you run `sudo evtest`, the second one you should see in `jstest-gtk`. Both should be named "PLAYSTATION(R)3 Controller Motion Sensors forwarded". Is any of those devices created?

Comment: As it turned out, `uinput` is not user-accessible by default. I edited my answer, please look at the new udev rule: I added one line. It should now work, at least it does in a fresh ubuntu 18.04.2 VM. Since I had steam installed on the system where I tested it, I didn't need that line because steam already added it in another rule.